# Problem with installig package lxml Python using PyCharm GUI

Tags: pycharm, lxml

I have a problem with installing package named xmlx.
I type `pip install xmlx` in CMD, and everything was fine, it was successful.
But when i try to add this package in PyCharm I got error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> "Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'D:\msys2\mingw64\bin\python.exe'."

What is wrong? I just have installed last version of pip and xmlx package...

Comment: Can you say what OS your are using and explain the `\mingw64` path? When you say *"add the package in PyCharm"* what exactly do you mean by that, writing an import? Did you [activate the venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) before install and before use?

Comment: i use Windows, by ""add the package in PyCharm" i mean that i found it in "python packages" and click install, i always did it and everytime it was fine.

Comment: So your question is about why it works using the terminal but not using the PyCharm GUI?

Comment: yes why i cant use it in PyCharm 
despite the i add it in PyCharm packages, like every package i have used.

Comment: Good question, I'm not entirely sure but there are [a few threads for the same error message you are getting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22Try%20to%20run%20this%20command%20from%20the%20system%20terminal.%20Make%20sure%20that%20you%20use%20the%20correct%20version%20of%20%27pip%22) but with different packages. Probably one of them has the same or very similar causes.

Comment: I read those topics but i havent found answear...

Comment: Now i add a 'opepyxl' by pip and then did the same steps in pycharm and everything is fine... but problem with lxml is still